# I am working with table in MS Word, when I press Enter in last column, I find extra space height in bottom of table row i.e. between two table row

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am working with MS Word-2010 Table in my column height is not fixed some row very little and some are big. When I press Enter to new row result above table show extra height space. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Enter likely added a new line to the column's data,
in this way increasing its height and that of the row.

The correct key to navigate columns is the Tab, not Enter.